# Jinja and javascript syntax conflict?

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, jinja2

I am using jinja2 templating language in my GAE-python project.
I have tried to use the [jquery-upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) for uploading files.

The following code is throwing an error:

```
<!-- The template to display files available for upload -->¬
    152 <script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">¬
--  153     {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}¬
|   154     <tr class="template-upload fade">¬
|   155         <td class="preview"><span class="fade"></span></td>¬
|-  156         <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>¬
```

The above code is directly taken from the jquery upload library.

The error:

```
line 153, in template
    {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ')', got 'i'
```

I think it is being caused due to the `{% %}` which is used by jinja2 as well as the text/x-tmpl js syntax. Is this correct? If so, 
How can I work around it? Please help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
{{ '{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}' }}
```

Or you can use {% raw %} {% endraw %} blocks.

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#escaping

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems while using Flask and Angular. That helped!
Figured it might be helpful for other people.

http://flask-triangle.readthedocs.org/en/develop/tutorial/part1.html